# Is there a way to return the last occurrence of duplicate values and/or unique value of one column to another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In layman's term, I'm trying to resolve the following: If cell A2 in column A is unique, then return the value of cell A2 in cell B2. And if cell A6 in column A is the last occurrence of duplicate values in column A, then return in cell B6; if not, leave blank/null/0/etc.

Here's a screenshot of what I need the result to look like. The light colors are the duplicates I don't want, and the darker colors are the last occurrence I want to return to column B.

If possible, I'm trying to find the simplest function to make this possible, as I'm working with quite a large excel sheet. Thanks so much for your help!

[image: example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this perhaps:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),A2,"null")
```

Comment: That will depend on whether you're using Sheets or Excel. If Sheets, change `A$2:A$10` to `A2:A`. If Excel, change to `A:A`.